# Google GCM with Cordova error

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

After adding, [Cordova GCM push plugins](https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin/) I faced a few issues with my build and did resolve it as seen on this [thread](https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin/issues/16).

Recently, the build started to fail again, with this exception:

```
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+, but version 8.3.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
```

I assume, this came from the following from `build.gradle` file inside `platform/android`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+" // This line in particular
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

It is not possible to edit this file directly, so I have created a `build-extras.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy{
        force ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0")
    }
}
```

But I am not able to resolve it. I still get the same error as noted above.

Google specifies an error similar to this in the [8.3 release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases). As noted there, I have specified the version, updated my build tools, play services repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced that problem with another plugin, and I fixed it with this hook in after_platform_add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fork = require('child_process').fork,
    shell = require("shelljs");

var dir = './platforms/android/';
if (fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.writeFileSync(dir + 'build-extras.gradle', 'configurations { all*.exclude group: \'com.android.support\', module: \'support-v4\'}', 'utf8');
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: I could directly add this configuration to build-extras.gradle. But I will try your approach. But mostly this is for multiple dex files, right?

Comment: It is not working! Facebook connect plugin that I using is throwing out some error.